# I want to use the Graph API to get any user ID, what do I need to send to Facebook api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to use the Graph API to get any user ID, what do I need to send to Facebook api?

https://graph.facebook.com/100009031494361?access_token=....

```
{
 "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '100009031494361' does 
       not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions,
       or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation 
       at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",

      "type": "GraphMethodException",

      "code": 100,

      "error_subcode": 33,

      "fbtrace_id": "AT-imffjNk6PZJGyIE4m6kG"

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to retrieve the userID you can use the [/me endpoint](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#me):

> ```
> /me
> ```
>
> The /me node is a special endpoint that translates to the user_id of
>   the person (or the page_id of the Facebook Page) whose access token is
>   currently being used to make the API calls

As example following curl:

```
curl -i -X GET \
 "https://graph.facebook.com/v4.0/me?fields=id,name&access_token=<the_token>"
```

Hope this help

Comment: thank you.
But what I want is to have someone else's post

Comment: @vietho then you will have to make them login to your app and grant it permission first. You can not access any data about other users willy-nilly any more.

Comment: I want to do news gathering software, is there any way to help me collect their articles?